# how to set autolayout for static table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am a beginner, but I usually don't have a problem to set autolayout. but I am confused when trying to set autolayout for my static table view. here is the screen I want to set

[image]

as we can see below, there is a grey area in the bottom of my static table view, and I want to get rid of it, if the device is bigger, the grey area is also bigger.

[image]

I thought that I can set the table view constraint top bottom left and right to be zero to get rid of that grey area, but I can't set the value of the contraint

[image]

[image]
so how to get rid of that grey area?

Comment: Use UIViewController instead of UITableViewController if you are using single cell in view to manage user space.

Comment: Get a smaller screen? It has to be some color, what do you want it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run you app in simulator or actual device you will not see that grey area. As you are now seeing in Storyboard preview.

Comment: when I run the app in simulator, that grey area is still there i.stack.imgur.com/sd5lR.png  :(

Comment: @AgungLaksana That is white area

Comment: @AgungLaksana as your static content height is less then your `UITableView` that's why you are seeing that white area.

Comment: Oh OK, I get it now, it seems it will be better if i just use UI View Controller. Thanks